# Combinatorics, number theory, rhombic rectangular prism

Tags: combinatorics

$$
1\cdot 2+2 \cdot 3+3 \cdot 4+\ldots+n\cdot(n+1)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3},
$$
right???

So will $\dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}+1$ form a rhombic rectangular pyramid?

Comment: What do you mean by [an expression] forming [a geometric shepe] ? Does 1+1 form a heart? Perhaps some context would be useful ...

Comment: @MattiP. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figurate_number

Comment: It's like how how {n(n+1)}/2 forms triangular numbers and n triangular numbers added together gives the n+1th tetrahedral number?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean.

For $1\cdot2+2\cdot3+\cdots+n\cdot(n+1)$ (hence without the extra $+1$), you can get the following, for $n=5$:

[image]

However, it doesn't really look like a pyramid.

Of course, with $1\cdot1+2\cdots2+\cdots+n\cdot n$, it's easy to get a pyramid:

[image]

You should explain a little bit what you mean by a pyramid in this context, and why, with $\frac13n(n+1)(n+2)+1$, you expect to get a pyramid.